# gulp-rev generating new file name for same code base

Tags: javascript, angularjs, gulp, gulp-rev

Working on a codebase that has used the [yeoman angular generator (1.4.x)](https://github.com/Swiip/generator-gulp-angular).

`gulp-rev` is getting used and it's generating a new file (hash) name every single time even for the same code base, how can I keep the same file hash?

Here's the main task that's building it (I suppose),

```
gulp.task('html', ['inject', 'partials'], function () {
  var partialsInjectFile = gulp.src(path.join(conf.paths.tmp, '/partials/templateCacheHtml.js'), { read: false });
  var partialsInjectOptions = {
    starttag: '<!-- inject:partials -->',
    ignorePath: path.join(conf.paths.tmp, '/partials'),
    addRootSlash: false
  };

  var htmlFilter = $.filter('*.html', { restore: true });
  var jsFilter = $.filter('**/*.js', { restore: true });
  var cssFilter = $.filter('**/*.css', { restore: true });

  return gulp.src(path.join(conf.paths.tmp, '/serve/*.html'))
    .pipe($.inject(partialsInjectFile, partialsInjectOptions))
    .pipe($.useref())
    .pipe(jsFilter)
    .pipe($.sourcemaps.init())
    .pipe($.ngAnnotate())
    .pipe($.uglify({ preserveComments: $.uglifySaveLicense })).on('error', conf.errorHandler('Uglify'))
    .pipe($.rev())
    .pipe($.sourcemaps.write('maps'))
    .pipe(jsFilter.restore)
    .pipe(cssFilter)
    // .pipe($.sourcemaps.init())
    .pipe($.replace('../../bower_components/bootstrap-sass/assets/fonts/bootstrap/', '../fonts/'))
    .pipe($.cssnano())
    .pipe($.rev())
    // .pipe($.sourcemaps.write('maps'))
    .pipe(cssFilter.restore)
    .pipe($.revReplace())
    .pipe(htmlFilter)
    .pipe($.htmlmin({
      removeEmptyAttributes: true,
      removeAttributeQuotes: true,
      collapseBooleanAttributes: true,
      collapseWhitespace: true
    }))
    .pipe(htmlFilter.restore)
    .pipe(gulp.dest(path.join(conf.paths.dist, '/')))
    .pipe($.size({ title: path.join(conf.paths.dist, '/'), showFiles: true }));
});
```

**STYLES TASK**

```
'use strict';

var path = require('path');
var gulp = require('gulp');
var conf = require('./conf');

var browserSync = require('browser-sync');

var $ = require('gulp-load-plugins')();

var wiredep = require('wiredep').stream;
var _ = require('lodash');

gulp.task('styles-reload', ['styles'], function() {
  return buildStyles()
    .pipe(browserSync.stream());
});

gulp.task('styles', function() {
  return buildStyles();
});

var buildStyles = function() {
  var sassOptions = {
    outputStyle: 'expanded',
    precision: 10
  };

  var injectFiles = gulp.src([
    path.join(conf.paths.src, '/app/**/*.scss'),
    path.join('!' + conf.paths.src, '/app/app.scss')
  ], { read: false });

  var injectOptions = {
    transform: function(filePath) {
      filePath = filePath.replace(conf.paths.src + '/app/', '');
      return '@import "' + filePath + '";';
    },
    starttag: '// injector',
    endtag: '// endinjector',
    addRootSlash: false
  };


  return gulp.src([
    path.join(conf.paths.src, '/app/app.scss')
  ])
    .pipe($.inject(injectFiles, injectOptions))
    .pipe(wiredep(_.extend({}, conf.wiredep)))
    .pipe($.sourcemaps.init())
    .pipe($.sass(sassOptions)).on('error', conf.errorHandler('Sass'))
    .pipe($.autoprefixer()).on('error', conf.errorHandler('Autoprefixer'))
    .pipe($.sourcemaps.write())
    .pipe(gulp.dest(path.join(conf.paths.tmp, '/serve/app/')));
};
```

**SCRIPTS TASK**

```
'use strict';

var path = require('path');
var gulp = require('gulp');
var conf = require('./conf');

var browserSync = require('browser-sync');

var $ = require('gulp-load-plugins')();


gulp.task('scripts-reload', function() {
  return buildScripts()
    .pipe(browserSync.stream());
});

gulp.task('scripts', function() {
  return buildScripts();
});

function buildScripts() {
  return gulp.src(path.join(conf.paths.src, '/app/**/*.js'))
    .pipe($.eslint())
    .pipe($.eslint.format())
    .pipe($.size())
};
```

[Found this piece](https://github.com/sindresorhus/gulp-rev#different-hash-for-unchanged-files) on the gulp-rev github page but,
I'm not good at gulp, so don't know what to change and where in the task here.

Answer (score 0):

The stated purpose of gulp-rev is to do this:

> Static asset revisioning by appending content hash to filenames unicorn.css → unicorn-d41d8cd98f.css

The idea is to be able to cache these static files, but still deliver the latest code to the user. If you didn't want to revision your assets, you can simply take it out from your pipeline:

```
return gulp.src(path.join(conf.paths.tmp, '/serve/*.html'))
.pipe($.inject(partialsInjectFile, partialsInjectOptions))
.pipe($.useref())
.pipe(jsFilter)
.pipe($.sourcemaps.init())
.pipe($.ngAnnotate())
.pipe($.uglify({ preserveComments: $.uglifySaveLicense })).on('error', conf.errorHandler('Uglify'))
.pipe($.sourcemaps.write('maps'))
.pipe(jsFilter.restore)
.pipe(cssFilter)
// .pipe($.sourcemaps.init())
.pipe($.replace('../../bower_components/bootstrap-sass/assets/fonts/bootstrap/', '../fonts/'))
.pipe($.cssnano())
// .pipe($.sourcemaps.write('maps'))
.pipe(cssFilter.restore)
.pipe(htmlFilter)
.pipe($.htmlmin({
  removeEmptyAttributes: true,
  removeAttributeQuotes: true,
  collapseBooleanAttributes: true,
  collapseWhitespace: true
}))
.pipe(htmlFilter.restore)
.pipe(gulp.dest(path.join(conf.paths.dist, '/')))
.pipe($.size({ title: path.join(conf.paths.dist, '/'), showFiles: true 
}));
```

Comment: I agree, but this is apparently causing some issue for the server to cache it. 
From the link I posted, I'm looking to implement the following,

`To avoid generating a new hash for unchanged source files, you can:

Sort the streams with gulp-sort
Filter unchanged files with gulp-unchanged
Read more about incremental builds`